# What is the default value for "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" of PostgreSQL in CloudSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I spent more time to figure out this problem, but get nothing. Does anyone know the answer?

Or teach me how to set the value `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` in CloudSQL.

Comment: `show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;`

Comment: Thanks !!! But i still don't know how to adjust the value in PostgreSQL of CloudSQL. Do you have any idea ?